# Going from datetimeoffset to datetime

Tags: sql, datetime, datetimeoffset

I'm working on modifying a query used to pull data in an SSIS package. It consists of 3 unions, of which all the former subqueries work fine, however the last query is returning a "conversion of a datetimeoffset data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value" error. I'm thinking it might be due to the PolicyExpirationDate field containing nulls, for policies which aren't expired yet. I tried applying what I did in the other subqueries of the union, but no luck.

Here is the subquery which is returning the error (along with my commented out attempts to fix the error):

```
select DISTINCT
    P.PolicyNumber    
    ,S.RatingPeriod   'RatingPeriodNumber'   
    , 'VES' as 'RatingPeriodSource'     
    ,P.Id 'PcmPolicyId'    
    ,CONVERT(datetime,P.PolicyEffectiveDate) AS PolicyEffectiveDate   
    ,CONVERT(datetime,P.PolicyExpirationDate) AS PolicyExpirationDate   
    --, ISNULL(CONVERT(datetime,P.PolicyExpirationDate),'2030-12-31') AS PolicyExpirationDate   
    --CONVERT(datetime, '2010-07-25T13:50:38.544', 126) AS PolicyExpirationDate    
    --,CONVERT(datetime, P.PolicyExpirationDate, 126) AS PolicyExpirationDate  
    , 'Coverage'  as 'Level'    
    , pcsf.Name 'Factor_Name'    
    , pcsf.value 'Factor_Amount'   
    ,(select max(s2.Id) from PolicyStatus S2 where s.PolicyId = s2.PolicyId and s.RatingPeriod = s2.RatingPeriod)     'PS_PolicyTransID'    
    ,CONVERT(datetime,(select max(s2.EffectiveDate) from PolicyStatus S2 where s.PolicyId = s2.PolicyId and s.RatingPeriod = s2.RatingPeriod)) 'ActivationDate'
from 
    policy p
    inner JOIN     PolicyStatus  s    ON s.PolicyId = P.Id    
    inner join policyschema ps on ps.policyid = p.id         --get schema used on the policy   
    left outer join policyschemacoveragecontainer pscc on pscc.SchemaId = ps.id    --get coverage level factors   
    left outer join policyschemacoverage psc on psc.containerid = pscc.id   
    left outer join policycoverageschemafactor pcsf on pcsf.coverageid = psc.id    and pcsf.IsSelected = 1
where pcsf.Name not like 'Minimum Monthly Premium'
```

Comment: Date range for `datetime` data type lies from `January 1, 1753, through December 31, 9999` while for `datetime2` data type lies from `0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31`. One of the possible reason may be as you have pointed are the nulls in `PolicyExpirationDate` or there are dates outside the range handled by the target `datetime` data type.

Comment: To test @Deepshikha's idea, what do you get from `SELECT MIN(p.PolicyEffectiveDate) AS MinDt, MAX(p.PolicyEffectiveDate) AS MaxDt FROM policy AS p...`? Might be informative. Might not be.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys. This is what I get when I try your suggestion: MinDt: 2017-07-05 00:00:00.0000000 -04:00 and MaxDt: 2018-12-20 00:00:00.0000000 -05:00, so they're within range. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I see three fields you're attempting to convert.  Did you also check `Policy.PolicyExpirationDate` and `PolicyStatus.EffectiveDate`?

Comment: If you are SQL 2012+, use `try_convert(datetime,P.PolicyEffectiveDate)`. That will maintain your `null` values (or make nonconvertible values to null). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks, Shawn. The Try_Convert did the trick!